# Snap package with QT4 application cannot find sql database driver

Tags: snap, qt4

I try to build a snapcraft file for an open source project which uses QT4 and sqLite. Building worked fine after few iterations, but now, I can't start the program. There seem to be two problems:

- fonts are messed up ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlMcO.png))
- the db driver cannot be loaded

I focus on the latter:

```
QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: 
Cannot open DB
```

I see that the file `libqsqlite.so` is in the snap. It seems that the database driver path is hardcoded to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/`, somewhere in the pre-built QT libraries, but all files in the snap are mounted to `/snap/beurerscalemanager/current/`, so I need to redirect this somehow.
Most obvious was to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but the library was still not found.
I also found information about a `/qt/etc/qt.conf`, but this looks again like an absolute path which I cannot influence from inside the snap.

What's the proper way to fix this?

Here is my `snapcraft.yaml`:

```
name: beurerscalemanager
version: git
title: Beurer Scale Manager
summary: Beurer Scale Manager
description: |
    This project would be a Linux replacement for the Beurer HealthManager (Windows).
grade: devel
license: GPL-3.0

confinement: strict
#confinement: devmode
base: core18

apps:
  beurerscalemanager:
    command: "BeurerScaleManager"
    plugs:
    - hardware-observe
    - raw-usb
    - x11
    #- home
    #environment:
    #  "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "$SNAP/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers"

parts:
  beurerscalemanager:
    plugin: cmake
    source-type: git
    source: https://github.com/Urban82/BeurerScaleManager.git
    build-packages:
      - libusb-1.0-0-dev
      - pkg-config
      - libqt4-dev
    stage-packages:
      - libusb-1.0-0
      - libqt4-sql
      - libqt4-sql-sqlite
      - libsqlite3-0
      - libqtcore4
      - libqtgui4
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the plugin path using an environment variable, found deep in the [Qt4 documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#libraryPaths):

```
    environment:
      QT_PLUGIN_PATH: "$SNAP/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/"
```

Not nice is the hard-coded architecture part of the path. But it seems that's a common problem on envvars in `snapcraft.yaml`. I would expect something like `$SNAP_ARCH` but that one contains the string `amd64`